# imagecreatefromjpeg exhausted memory limit, but it's wrong

Tags: php

I set the `memory_limit` in my PHP config files to 100MB.
I have an image uploading script, that is working OK for some small images, but I tried to upload a relatively large image (13MB), and got the following error:

```
Allowed memory size of 104857600 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 45056 bytes)
```

which points to this line: `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($file['tmp_name']);`

What is the cause for it being exhausted if it's much lower than the limit, ad it tries to allocate only 45056 Bytes, which are only 0.045 MB?

Thanks

Comment: It tried to allocate some *additional* 45056 bytes, but that allocation request exceeded the limit of 104857600. It already had used more than 104857600 - 45056 bytes.

Comment: why are you trying to reinvent the image? you aren't resizing it, so just move the file.

Comment: Thanks, had a feeling that it's additional, just wanted to be sure.
It's a script where a user uploads a photo, and allows him to rotate, resize, drag around, so I have to use imagecreatefromjpeg. What's causing it to allocate this huge amount of memory though?

Comment: A 13 MB JPEG is, roughly guesstimating, somewhere in the range of 5000 x 5000 pixels times at least 3 bytes per pixel (RGB) equals somewhere around 100 MB of memory for the decoded image (if I'm getting this right). So, really bumping right up to the limit there.

Comment: Alright, I thought that JPEG size is: what you see - is what you actually have. Didn't realize PHP has to decode, you should make an answer so that I can pick it up if you wish, thank you! Btw you were nearly correct: The height is 5000 pixels, width is 10,000 pixels (I intentionally downloaded a large photo to test my script)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not *wrong*, you're just misunderstanding what it's telling you. It tries to allocate an *additional* 45056 bytes to whatever memory it already had, and that exceeded the limit of 104857600.

As for why an image uses that much memory: JPEG is a compressed storage format. In order to display it on screen, the computer needs to know each individual pixel. Each pixel has three colour values (in some image formats even more, plus perhaps a transparency layer) each typically 1 byte large (some formats use even more, others less). Given an image 5000 by 10000 pixels that's:

```
5000 * 10000 * 3 / 1024 / 1024 = 143.0511474609 MB
```

To store all pixels in memory at once so it can manipulate or display the image, you need 143 MB of free RAM. Basically, convert the JPEG into a BMP and you know how much space it *really* takes.